# How to run PostgreSQL server with Firebase Functions?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run PostgreSQL server with Firebase Functions. And `$ npm run build` runs but `$ firebase serve --only functions` doesn't work sending error:

```sh
import {
>    ^^^^^^
>     
>    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

(error at **Entity file**)

I'm using

- TypeScript
- Firebase Functions
- PostgreSQL

and **here's my code**:

- `index.ts`

  ````js
  import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
  import { router } from './routers'
  import Koa from 'koa'
  import { createConnection } from 'typeorm'


  export const app = new Koa()
  const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 8080

  app.proxy = true
  app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods())

  const dbServer = async () => {
     try {
         await createConnection()
         app.listen(PORT, () => {
         console.log(`Listening to port ${PORT}`)
       })
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
     }
   }

  dbServer()

  export const api = functions
     .region('asia-northeast3')
     .https.onRequest(app.callback())
   ```
  ````
- `entity/Channel.ts`

  ```js
  import {
      BaseEntity,
      Entity,
      PrimaryGeneratedColumn
  } from 'typeorm'

  @Entity('Channel')
  export class Channel extends BaseEntity {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
      id: number
  }
  ```

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Functions are designed for running relatively short-lived processes. The maximum time a single Cloud Function can be active is 9 minutes, after which its container will shut the code down. This means that Cloud Functions can not be reasonably used for running your own database server, or other long-lived processes.

Consider using a hosted database service, like Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! I also wondered if I could run db server on top of cloud functions haha... So I need separate service like cloud sql to run db server! Thank you so much